# Unexpected behavior onActivityResult when accessing member adapter of listview inside

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm using this to start an activity for result

```
    Intent pickIntent = new Intent(this, PickerActivity.class);
    pickIntent.putExtra(PickerActivity.OBJECTS, new String[] { "One", "Two" });
    pickIntent.putExtra(PickerActivity.TITLE, getString(R.string.dummyTitle));
    startActivityForResult(pickIntent, PickerActivity.REQUEST);
```

and i get this called after the selection

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (requestCode == PickerActivity.REQUEST)
    {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
        {
            adapter.add(data.getStringExtra("result"));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // Not required but put to prove a point
        }
    }
}
```

The list view that holds the adapter is not updated.

However it works if i use

```
        adapterData.add(data.getStringExtra("result")); // The list that was passed to the list adapter
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

or even

```
        Handler mainHandler = new Handler(context.getMainLooper());

        Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                 adapter.add(data.getStringExtra("result"));
            }
        };
        mainHandler.post(myRunnable);
```

Can someone explain why?

Comment: What object is `adapter`?

Comment: It's just an ArrayAdapter<String>